# Google Nexus 5 not syncing with my ubuntu 14.04 after last Android update 6.0

Tags: nexus-5x

My Google Nexus 5 won't sync with my Ubuntu 14.04 after last Android update 6.0

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125140 or https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/37z47l/android_m_mtp_not_working/?

Comment: Not at all a problem with Ubuntu. If Ubuntu stayed the same and Android changed, logically this would be an Android problem. [android.se]

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen the links posted by @muru yet, basically:

1. Plug your Nexus 5 into the PC
2. Unlock the phone
3. Open the notifications shade, then tap on "USB for Charging" (this doesn't show up in the status bar as it's a low priority notification).
4. Tap on "Transfer files (MTP)".
5. Check the file manager sidebar on your PC. It should come up with "Nexus 5" (or whatever your device is called) if it mounts normally.

If this doesn't work, try using the other options, like PTP or MIDI. If none of those is being picked up by the PC, try another cable. If that still doesn't work, there might be a problem with the computer. In that event, test it on a another computer, then post your findings here.
Hopefully it shouldn't go that far though, especially since you've had the problem since the 6.0 update.